# Разработать приложение контакты , с проверкой необходимых данных

Tags: android

Нужно разработать приложение контакты (Имя,Фамилия,Телефон,Дата Рождения) и назначить необходимую проверку введенных данных
как сделать проверку вводимых данных?

вот метод write Он записывает все вводимые данные в файл

```
public void write(View view) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(super.getFilesDir(), "laba6.txt");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(edit.getText().toString()  + "\n"+edit2.getText().toString() +"\n"+ edit3.getText().toString()+"\n"
                + edit4.getText().toString() + "\r");
        bw.close();
        edit.setText("");//очищаем текстовое поле
        edit2.setText("");
        edit3.setText("");
        edit4.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Текст сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//показываем смс
        //fileOutput.write(String.format("%s %s %s %s", myTxt, myTxt1, myTxt2, myTxt3).getBytes());


    }
```

Comment: По моему рациональней использовать SQLite.

Comment: нет,по заданию нужно сделать именно так

Comment: Так в чем тогда проблема? Записали данные, проверили их.. И при не соответствии побили тревогу. Есть equals().. а можно разбить на символы.. Можно еще разбивать по маякам типа text.split("маяк")..

Comment: а вот как именно сделать проверку? я не могу понять